Is there a way to highlight replacement in figures for paper revision?
I am performing a review for a paper and I have to provide two files, namely a CLEAN VERSION, with no marked changes and a MARKED VERSION in which I will mark the revisions. For the text I am using the usepackage[changes] with the commands \added{}, \deleted{} and \replaced{}{}. I am trying to replace a figure with a new one and I am searching for a way to show this replacement. Do you have anything on your mind?

Please, do read the package documentation.
On page 30 it says:

Change markup of texts works well, it is possible to markup whole paragraphs. You cannot markup:
– figures
– tables
– headings
– some commands
– several paragraphs (sometimes)
You can try putting such text in an extra file and include in with input. This works sometimes, give it a try. Kudos to Charly Arenz for this tip.

I recommend you try it and let us know.

I know that it does not work for figures. Also, I cannot understand what it means by "putting such text in an extra file and include in with input.".

@Kosmylo, then why not search for it? You would be surprised what you can find even on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

I did it. It does not work.


This custom solution works
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\NewDocumentCommand{\figReplace}{}{figreplace}
\tcbset{\figReplace/.style=
    {
        % spacings
        size=minimal,
        top=0.50pt, bottom=0.50pt,
        left=0.50pt, right=0.50pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        % rules
        toprule=0.1pt,   bottomrule=0.1pt,
        leftrule=0.1pt,  rightrule=0.1pt,
        % enlargement and extrusion
        enlarge left by=1em, enlarge right by=1em,
        enlarge top by=2.5em, enlarge bottom by=1em,
        extrude left by=1em, extrude right by=1em,
        extrude top by=2.5em, extrude bottom by=1em,
        % rules
        arc=0pt,
        % colors
        colframe=black, colback=Ivory1,
        % opacity
        opacityframe=1, opacityback=1,
        % text
        fontupper=\normalfont,
        % overlay to indicate image replacement
        enhanced jigsaw,
        finish={\node[anchor=north, opacity=0.75, color=gray] at (frame.north) {\huge Replaced Image};}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[\figReplace]
        
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}

